# Tabular with minipage inside, problem with vertical alignment

Tags: tables, minipage, alignment

I am trying to align two minipages inside a tabular environment, but I have some alignment issues when I put more than one table, as you can see in the image at the bottom.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
\textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\begin{document}

\section*{References}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr A}\\
AAA University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.a@aaauniversity.com}{mr.a@aaauniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr B}\\
BBB University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}{mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular} \\ \\

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr C}\\
CCC University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.c@cccuniversity.com}{mr.c@cccuniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr D}\\
DDD University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.d@ddduniversity.com}{mr.d@ddduniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

For this you not need `minipage` nested in `tabular`. Rather redefine columns type as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
\textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\section*{References}
\begin{tabular}{|P{3in}|P{3in}}
\textbf{Mr A}   \\
AAA University  \\
Somewhere       \\
In the world    \\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.a@aaauniversity.com}{mr.a@aaauniversity.com}
&
\textbf{Mr B}   \\
BBB University  \\
Somewhere       \\
In the world    \\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}{mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}
                        \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}    \tabularnewline[2ex]
\textbf{Mr C}   \\
CCC University  \\
Somewhere       \\
In the world    \\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.c@cccuniversity.com}{mr.c@cccuniversity.com}
&
\textbf{Mr D}   \\
DDD University  \\
Somewhere       \\
In the world    \\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.d@ddduniversity.com}{mr.d@ddduniversity.com}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only forgot that a blank lines starts a new paragraph, so the second `tabular` should be introduced  by a `\noindent` command.

That being said, your tables are too wide for the default layout. Also, why don't you use one of the `p` or `b` or `X` column types?

```
\documentclass[10pt, table]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{marvosym} % For cool symbols.
\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
\textbf{#1}\newline% Name
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\begin{document}

\section*{References}
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr A}\\
AAA University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.a@aaauniversity.com}{mr.a@aaauniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr B}\\
BBB University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}{mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular} \\ \\

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c}
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr C}\\
CCC University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.c@cccuniversity.com}{mr.c@cccuniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
\textbf{Mr D}\\
DDD University\\
Somewhere\\
In the world\\
\Telefon\ +99 99 99 99 99 99\\
\Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.d@ddduniversity.com}{mr.d@ddduniversity.com}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 [...]
            \Letter\ \href{mailto:mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}{mr.b@bbbuniversity.com}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular} \\[\bigskipamount]
%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}
            \textbf{Mr C}\\
[...]
```

and also not something like `\\ \\` in a tabular.

[image]

Comment: What should be done instead of `\\ \\ ` in a `tabular`? I ask because (in a different situation) I had the top of the contents in one row extending higher than it should, and overlapping the previous row. Some suggestions I found here in Tex.SE failed because they entailed knowing the height of one of the rows, then hard-coding it. But   `\\[-2mm] \\ ` did the trick.